# Why doesn't if statement preclude another if statement in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote a couple of if statements in Java. I wanted the first if statement to call a function called `newGame()` and not enter another if statement if true.

This is my if statement:

```
   if (numberOfTries == 0) {
       message = "You lost! Try again!";
       System.out.println("Setting label you lost: " + message);
       newGame();
   }
   if (guess < theNumber) {
       message = guess + " is too low. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
       System.out.println("Setting label too low: " + message);
   }
   else if (guess > theNumber) {
       message = guess + " is too high. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
       System.out.println("Setting label too high: " + message);
   }
   else {
       message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
       System.out.println("Setting label is correct: " + message);
       newGame();
   }
```

It looks like the first if statement is executed, and then the second one gets executed as well.

For some reason my if statements only work if I combine them even though the tests seem unrelated:

```
   if (numberOfTries == 0) {
       message = "You lost! Try again!";
       System.out.println("Setting label you lost: " + message);
       newGame();
   }
   else if (guess < theNumber) {
       message = guess + " is too low. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
       System.out.println("Setting label too low: " + message);
   }
   else if (guess > theNumber) {
       message = guess + " is too high. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
       System.out.println("Setting label too high: " + message);
   }
   else {
       message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
       System.out.println("Setting label is correct: " + message);
       newGame();
   }
```

This is the whole method:

```
public void checkGuess() {
    String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
    txtGuess.setText("");// Empties the contents of the text field.
    String message = "";
    try {
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
        if (numberOfTries == 0) {
            message = "You Lost! A new game has begun and you have 8 guesses remaining.";
            newGame();
        }
        else if (guess < theNumber) {
            message = guess + " is too low. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
        }
        else if (guess > theNumber) {
            message = guess + " is too high. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
        }
        else {
            message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
            newGame();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Enter a whole number between 1 and 100.";
    } finally {
        lblOutput.setText(message);
        txtGuess.requestFocus();
        txtGuess.selectAll();
        
    }
    decrementNumberOfTries();
}
```

This is the separate `newGame()` function that gets called:

```
public void newGame() {
    numberOfTries = 8;
    theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}
```

I see the `numberOfTries == 0` test as separate from the `guess < theNumber` test. Why doesn't the first if test exclude the second if test?

Comment: Can you share the whole method ? It seems you call `newGame` from inside itself

Comment: Why *would* you expect unrelated `if`s to have an effect on one another (i.e. why would the first being executed stop the second from getting executed as well)? (unless, that is, `newGame` changes`guess` or `theNumber`)

Comment: Two separate `if` blocks have no knowledge of each other. While `if - else if -else` construct represent a single set of "rules".

Comment: Add the block of the second IF inside in the ELSE block of the first IF

Comment: `newGame` changes `theNumber`, that's why I thought  that the first  if statement would affect the second. I've expanded the OP to show the full  `checkGuess` and `newGame()` methods.

Comment: It only affects the second `if` if `theNumber` becomes smaller than `guess`, of course. But judging by what the game seems to do, the `else if` is the correct way to do this, since if you enter the first `if` the player turn (and by extension the whole game) is over, an no further check should be done from that point on. Even better, that `if` should be checked *after* you checked whether the player has the correct guess.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditional statements in java- `if` and `if else`:

```
if (condition) {
    <code to run>
}


if (condition) {
    <code to run if condition is true>
} else {
    <code to run if condition is false>
}
```

While you can make `else if` statements, they are an abbreviated form of:

```
if (condition) {
    <code to run if condition is true>
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        <code to run if condition is true (and previous condition is false)>
    }
}
```

In none of those conditional statements does an `if` statement rely on a previous `if` statement unless it is inside of an `else` statement.

While using `else if` is customary (for every language because of its readablity), you *could* make each if statement dependant of the previous with:

```
if (condition1) {
    <code to run if true>
}
if (condition2 && !condition1) {
    <code to run if condition1 is false and condition2 is true>
}
if (condition3 && !condition2 && !condition1) {
    <code to run if condition1 and condition2 are false and condition3 is true>
}
```

This is also slower than `else if` statements, so I wouldn't recommend it.